# asp.net getting xml from a proc?

Tags: asp.net, xml

i have a stored proc that uses FOR XML and wanted to know how to load the xml in my asp.net c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the asp.net forums site:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
SqlConnection cnn = null;
SqlCommand cmd = null;
try
{
      cnn = new SqlConnection();
      cnn.ConnectionString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
      cnn.Open();

      string selectQry = "SELECT [Xml] FROM [Table1] WHERE [PK_ID] = @ID";
      cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQry, cnn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

      XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

      if (reader.Read())
         xdoc.Load(reader);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      throw ex;
}
finally
{
      cmd.Dispose();
      cnn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load it into an xml document object...

XmlDocument docXml = new XmlDocument();
docXml.LoadXml(stringReturnedFromStoredProc);

You can then loop through the nodes or use XPath to do what you need to do with the xmldoc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "sProcName";
string connStr = "connectionString";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
        p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        p.ParameterName = "@resultXML";
        p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

        adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;
        result = adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string resultXML = (string)p.Value;

        XElement xml = XElement.Parse(resultXML);
    }
}
```